A lower bound for $|g^{2n}|$ in terms of $|g^{n}|$
I'm trying to follow the proof of Theorem 7.1.1 from Alessandro Sisto's lecture notes on Geometric Group Theory and would like some help understanding a claim he makes.
He presents his Lemma 7.2.2, which states (I have corrected what seems to be a typo) :

There exists $C$ with the following property. For every $n\geq 0$, we have $d(g^n, [1,g^{2n}]) \leq C.$

Here $g$ is an infinite order element of a finitely generated $\delta$-Hyperbolic group $G$, $[1, g^{2n}]$ denotes a geodesic from $1$ to $g^{2n}$ in the Cayley graph of $G$, and the metric in question is the word metric.
He claims that a consequence of the lemma is that there exists $C>0$ (not necessarily the same $C$ perhaps) such that for all $n$ we have
$$ |g^{2n}| \geq 2|g^n| - C. $$
I don't see how this follows from the lemma, and would appreciate some insight here. As part of the proof of the lemma we consider an isosceles triangle with vertices at $1, g^n,$ and $g^{2n}$, and I tried playing around with this, but I wasn't able to bound $|g^{2n}|$ from below, and I don't really have any other avenues to approach this from...

Suppose that you knew that $g^n\in [1, g^{2n}]$. Do you see how to conclude in this case?

Yes, in this case we have $g^n$ is within $|g^{2n}|/2$ of at least one endpoint of $[1, g^{2n}]$, so either $d([1, g^n]) = |g^n| \leq |g^{2n}|/2$ or $d(g^n, g^{2n}) = d(1, g^n) \leq |g^{2n}|/2$. I think I get the idea!

Consider the isosceles triangle with vertices at $1, g^n,$ and $g^{2n}$, which we label by $X,Y,Z$ respectively. Note that $|XY| = |YZ| = |g^n|$ and $|XZ| = |g^{2n}|$. By the lemma stated in the question, there exists a point $W \in XZ$ with $|YW| \leq C$.

As $W \in XZ$, $W$ is within $|XZ|/2$ of either $X$ or $Z$. Assuming the former, we consider the triangle $\Delta XYW$, from which we conclude
$$ |g^n| = |XY| \leq |XW| + |WY| \leq \frac{|XZ|}{2} + C = \frac{|g^{2n}|}{2} + C, $$
and rearranging this expression gives the required inequality. A similar argument works in the case where $W$ is closer to $Z$ than $X$.
Many thanks to Moishe for the hint!
